# Вывод произвольных полей в плагине WordPress

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Не получается выводить (вызвать, подключить) произвольные поля в плагине. Опишу ситуацию - есть произв. поля, созданы плагином  Advanced Custom Fields (price_ru, price_kz, price_by, и т.д.). Выводил я их прямо в шаблоне темы + создавал новые файлы. Моя задача: собрать все в одном плагине, но передать содержимое полей не получается, я не знаю, как это сделать, пробовал по-разному:

```
global $post;
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_key' );
get_post_meta( $post->ID ,'my_key'
```

Comment: Скорее всего, выводите не в том месте плагина. Плагин инициализируется до создания основного цикла WordPress, переменная `$post` в этот момент ещё не существует, `get_the_ID()` не работает. Покажите код, как вы выводите, чтобы понять логику. В каком месте страницы должен сработать плагин и как вы это делаете.

Comment: KAGG Design спасибо. Ваше подсказка решила все "Плагин инициализируется до создания основного цикла WordPress"